# What methods do we have to understand the spectrum of matrices with restricted entries?

Tags: reference-request, linear-algebra, matrices, additive-combinatorics, convex-optimization

Consider questions of the form (or the "most probable value of" version of these questions rather than the "largest possible"),

- What is the largest possible spectral radius of a $n \times n$ matrix with entries in $\{0,1,-1 \}$ ?
- What is the largest possible spectral radius of a $n \times n$ matrix with entries in $\{0,1,-1 \}$ and has $d$ non-zero entries ? (or an "at most d" version of this)
- What is the largest possible spectral radius of a $n \times n$ matrix with entries in $\{0,1,-1 \}$ and which has $d$ non-zero entries in every row and/or column? (or an "at most d" version of this)

---

What methods or techniques we have to answer such things?
Any reference would be helpful.

---

One can restrict the matrices to be symmetric if necessary or to have $0$s along the diagonals if necessary. Or feel free to replace the set $\{0,1,-1\}$ by some other finite set if that makes things better.

Comment: The matrix with all $1$'s has spectral radius $r=n$, and this is obviously largest possible (normalize the eigenvector so that its largest entry is $1$).

Comment: Yeah. The first question is trivial. Should have noticed that. Though even in the first question the "most probable value of" version is not obvious to me.

Answer (score 3):

An easy argument that gives at least asymptotically the correct answer to the second question is obtained by considering the Hilbert-Schmidt norm: $\| A\|_2^2=\sum |a_{jk}|^2 = d$ and also $\|A\|_2^2 = \sum s_j(A)^2$ and $s_1(A)=\|A\|\ge r(A)$. So this shows that $r(A)\le\sqrt{d}$ for a matrix with $d$ non-zero $\pm 1$ entries.

Moreover, if $k^2\le d < (k+1)^2$, then you can get a matrix with $r(A)\ge k$ by putting a $k\times k$ block of $1$'s somewhere (and keeping the matrix symmetric, so that min-max can be used to see that the largest eigenvalue of this matrix is $\ge$ the largest eigenvalue $\lambda=k$ of the block of $1$'s); in fact, a more careful version of this argument produces slightly better bounds.

In general, $r(A)=\sqrt{d}$ is not always possible, though, as you can see from small examples ($d=n=2$).

Answer (score 2):

By [Gerschgorin's Circle Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gershgorin_circle_theorem), if the number of nonzero entries in each row is at most $d$, the spectral radius is at most $d$.  This bound is attained e.g. in a case where there are $d$ $1$'s  in each row and no $-1$'s, with eigenvector $(1,\ldots,1)^T$ for eigenvalue $d$.

EDIT: If the matrix has at most $d$ nonzero entries, the spectral radius is at most $ (d+1)/2$.  This follows from the following facts:

1. The spectrum is contained in the [numerical range](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_range), so the spectral radius is at most the numerical radius.
2. The numerical radius is a norm.
3. The numerical radius of a diagonal matrix with entries of $\pm 1$ and $0$ on the diagonal is $1$.
4. The numerical radius of a matrix with a single off-diagonal entry of $\pm 1$ and all else $0$ is $1/2$.

This estimate does not seem to be sharp (except of course if $d=1$).

Comment: This applies only when the entries are restricted to be from the set $\{ 0,1,-1\}$? (And is there a column version of this? Or restriction to symmetric ? Or with 0 on the diagonal version of this?)

Comment: Yes, this is with entries from $\{0,1,-1\}$.  Since $M$ and $M^T$ have the same spectrum, it's true for columns as well.